# Who calls commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've got a custom UITableViewCell that allows a user to input text when in edit mode. I've noticed that on stock UITableViewCells, when I swipe left, then hit the Delete button, it's table view receives the `commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath` message. I'm curious where this message is coming from. As far as I can tell, individual cells don't have a reference to the table view they belong to. If I want my custom cell to send this message, how would I go about doing that? I've thought about using the superview of the cell, but it seems like there's got to be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

This method gets called automatically (if you implement the data source protocol) before adding any row or column.
If you want to know to which table view a cell is belonging, use the superview method.

Comment: I know that it gets called automatically. I'm wondering how it gets called, because my custom cell doesn't have this behavior and I would like it to.

Comment: Ramy is right. In other words, your cell is free to call `[[[self superview] dataSource] tableView:[self superview] commitEditingStyle:theStyle forRowAtIndexPath:[[self superview] indexPathForCell:self]]`. However, you should probably not do this; don't misuse the framework. If you have something to say to the data source, say it more directly (i.e. devise your own messaging protocol).

Comment: @matt That's what I've done. I created a delegate class. I guess I was hoping there was a more direct way to do it.